# Array value multiplication doesen't work inside of the class

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a time calculation inside of an array which works fine stand alone but not inside of the class.

This works:

```php
<?php

$lifetime_array = array('lifetime' => 3600*24 );
echo $lifetime_array['lifetime'];
?>
```

Outputs correctly 86400

But this version dosen't work but should IMHO:

```php
<?php

class Test {
 private static $lifetime_array = array('lifetime' => 3600*24 );

    public static function outputLifetime()
    {
        echo self::$lifetime_array['lifetime'];
    }
}
Test::outputLifetime();

?>
```

Results in the error:

```php
Line : 5,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ')'
```

What's happening there? Is this a bug? And can it be avoided without doing all the calculacions by myself?

Comment: Shouldn't $lifetime_array in your second code sample be static for this to work?

Comment: `but should IMHO` your honest opinion is wrong. It will be only available in the future for simple operations https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs

Comment: @willem Maybe it should but it's not working in this case too. But thanx for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two cases is that the first one is a *variable declaration* while the other is a *property declaration*. In property declarations, you can only assign static values and nothing that has to be computed. See example #1 here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

A way to tackle this could be to make the necessary declaration within a constructor (a method that is automatically executed upon the object's creation). It could look like this:

```
<?php

class Test {
    private $lifetime_array;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lifetime_array = array('lifetime' => 3600 * 24);
    }

    public function outputLifetime()
    {
        echo $this->lifetime_array['lifetime'];
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->outputLifetime();

?>
```

If you wish to do this with a static property (as some of your code indicated), you would have to do this with a manually called static method:

```
<?php

class Test {
    private static $lifetime_array;

    public static function initialize()
    {
        self::$lifetime_array = array('lifetime' => 3600 * 24);
    }

    public static function outputLifetime()
    {
        echo self::$lifetime_array['lifetime'];
    }
}

Test::initialize();
Test::outputLifetime();

?>
```

Another possible way would be to define the value in a constant outside of the class:

```
<?php

define('SECONDS_IN_A_DAY', 3600 * 24);

class Test {
    private static $lifetime_array = array('lifetime' => SECONDS_IN_A_DAY);

    public static function outputLifetime()
    {
        echo self::$lifetime_array['lifetime'];
    }
}

Test::outputLifetime();

?>
```

Comment: A great explaination Hanzi and easy to understand. I'll take the define() workaround. Many thanx and wellcome here!

Answer (score 2):

change this line:

```
public static function outputLifetime(
```

to

```
public static function outputLifetime()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

- a typo inside method declaration
- if you want your methods to be static than the private property should be static too and **cannot** be initialized with expression only with constant values.

Comment: Thank you Ilan, you're right - there was a typo which ashames me a bit. Shouldn't happen. Yes, I also wanted it to be private static. Plus one from me.

Comment: You should also consider using a code linter to avoid those typos.
I use sublime text with phpcs plugin configured with psr-2 standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
This works 2

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Test {
 private  static  $lifetime_array = array();

    public static function outputLifetime()
    {
      echo self::$lifetime_array['lifetime'] = 3600*24;
    }
}

Test::outputLifetime();

?>
```